How would you make a city magical not just a setting but also as a character
I wanted to build a story where the main character is reincarnated into a fantasy novel and knows that there is no way that he will be able to keep up with the absurd increase in power of the main story characters and surmise that he will probably die as a side character so he decides to build a city. More specifically an altar to turn himself into a warlock of an artificial god.
I was inspired by Atlantis and Destiny from Stargate series and
Battlestar Galactica where the ships is more than just a setting but also a character. I also like A certain magical index series' Academy City where it's more than just a background.
I want the city to become a main focus and the main character just a vehicle to tell it's story. My current thoughts is to make a ritualistic city that meshes the mystical, the magical and the scientific to defend against enemies. Be it an assassin, an army or other demigods.
I want to know your suggestion on how you would make your city a character and how it would develop.
Also I kinda want the Mc to have a ritualistic innate talent for black magic so he can't go toe to toe with enemies but can prepare for them and still a remain a weak noble brat.

This question isn't really a good fit for this site.  Part of what you are asking is "how to write X", which belongs on WritingSE.  The other part is asking for suggestions about how to write your story, whic is explicitly off-topic for this site.  Please take the tour and have a look at what makes a good question here.

There is a famous and very popular entire series of novels by Iain Banks where city-sized sapient spaceships are first-class characters.... How did he do it? He did it by making the spaceships first-class characters. How do you make a city a first-class character? You simply make it a first-class character. You have the city feel stuff, you make the city do stuff, you make the city want stuff, you make the city hate stuff. You know, as any first-class character would.

In a slightly different form, you can ask some of this on the writing stack exchange https://writing.stackexchange.com/

In a literal since, you could give it an Avatar
To be a major character, the city most likely needs a way to talk to and interact with the characters.  You see this a lot in sci-fi where a ship's AI can holographically project itself or pop up on any computer terminal and make its own choices with the captain and crew only being there to guide it.  Likewise your city's avatar could be a ghost like apparition that appears before its citizens to discuss their needs and wants.
Just like the AIs on a starship, this ghost could control all sorts of things about the city: opening and closing of the gates, public access to water, maybe it runs the mills or magically fuels all of the towns forges and fireplaces.  Maybe it can even build and destroy buildings.  The more it can do, the more reason the people of the city have to talk to it, to get it to do (or not do) those things, and the more central it becomes as a charter.
But it's not completely necessary as long as it has power over people's lives.
One good example of this is the house from Encanto.  The house could add and remove rooms, it could move things around inside itself, and it could even become unwell, all without actually needing to say a word, you could see the house's relationship with the people though how it interacted with them.  As long as the city responds to the people inside in a way that implies a will of its own, it is for all intents and purposes, a character.
That said, even with the power to influence the environment, it is really hard to make the setting the "Main Character" if it does not have a voice, unless you write the story from the first person perspective of the city or from an omniscient narrator's perspective.  That way you can convey to your audience the mood, feelings, and motivations of the city without actually giving it a single speaking line.  AlexP gave a really good example of this in comments with the book White Fang.  If there is no path of expression connecting the audience to the setting, then it will most likely be seen as a supporting character to the more relatable humans within your story.

Why would the city (or in general any character in a story) need to talk? Characters don't need to talk. As a famous example, White Fang is a wolfdog, and does not talk; he barks, once. (And, just to show that White Fang is not alone, Rikki-Tikki-Tavi is mongoose.) And there is a concept of an unseen character, such as Terence's Girl from Andros, or Daudet's Arlésienne, or even Sauron in TLotR.

@AlexP "But it's not completely necessary as long as it has power over people's lives."  <- Yes, and I accounted for this in my answer. That said, White Fang does bring up how helpful a first person perspective is in turning a voiceless character into the "Main Character".  As for off-screen characters, the OP is specifically asking to make the city the main character; so, Sauron etc. don't quite fit.

"A first person perspective": White Fang is written in the third person. An unnamed narrator tells the story of White Fang. For example, "If ever a creature was the enemy of its kind, White Fang was that creature. He asked no quarter, gave none. He was continually marred and scarred by the teeth of the pack, and as continually he left his own marks upon the pack. Unlike most leaders, who, when camp was made and the dogs were unhitched, huddled near to the gods for protection, White Fang disdained such protection."

@AlexP ah, it's been about 25 years since I've read it; so, I was just remembering that wrong.  Omniscient narrators work too.
